# How to confirm that the licensing for a fresh install of Windows 10 is active and valid?

Tags: windows-10, installation, uefi, gpt, licensing

A trusted local computer shop provided a magical thumb drive, and after installing Windows I get:

```
PS C:\Users\saund>
PS C:\Users\saund>
PS C:\Users\saund> [System.Environment]::OSVersion.Version

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
10     0      19045  0


PS C:\Users\saund>
PS C:\Users\saund>  wmic  path softwarelicensingservice get OA3xOriginalProductKey
OA3xOriginalProductKey
XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX

PS C:\Users\saund>
```

where the product key is displayed, of course.  From the seller, on Amazon, they said that the Motherboard is registered and that all that's required is to install Windows.

Not sure [what I was doing wrong](https://askubuntu.com/q/1504211/847449), but for now this thumb drive would seem to have installed Windows correctly.  Leaving aside security concerns, what can be done to ensure that the licensing is up to par and correct?

*For context, I had installed Linux but now need Windows.  It was purchased refurbished, but the company selling was quite responsive about licensing inquiries.  They said to just install Windows 10 pro 64 bit.*

[image: winver]

Windows Script Host:

[image: script host]

for licensing details.

Comment: Which is what I had tried many times @John but UEFI had defeated me until using this other thumb drive from my local computer shop.

Comment: It is licensed to you

Comment: I am confused. Your screenshot shows your installation is activated. Your license key is never required with OEM hardware. What problem do you believe you have?

Comment: I wasn't sure that it was activated correctly.

Comment: It is activated and licensed to you.

Comment: @NicholasSaunders - You can check the activation status from within Settings.

Comment: What's the output of `cscript slmgr.vbs /dlv`, and is the product key findable on Google? The email address you see in "About Windows" has nothing to do with activation, it's just a registry setting.

Comment: I added that as an answer @u1686_grawity but would appreciate any explanation, if you'd care to post that as an answer yourself.

Comment: Okay, I'll post a screenshot.  I just wasn't sure at first.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From the seller, on Amazon, they said that the Motherboard is registered and that all that's required is to install Windows.

That's fairly common – Windows 10 activation causes a "digital license" to be registered at Microsoft, which will automatically be used in future installations on the same hardware even if you only provide a "generic" product key. (Microsoft's website has a table of such keys for each edition.)

So a refurbished mainboard is very likely to have one. If `cscript slmgr.vbs /dlv` says that you are on the `OEM_DM channel` then that's what you have.

If you want to be slightly more sure, you could replace your magical thumb drive with a *regular* Windows 10 thumb drive and see if it picks up the license. (Either automatically or after inserting the generic product key.)

Though note that there are methods to *manually* cause a digital license ticket to be generated and accepted by Microsoft even without having an actual license, e.g. this was possible to do using the "upgrade from Windows 7/8" procedure when it was still active. So you can never be 100% sure of whether the digital license was fully legitimate, although it doesn't *really* matter in the end – once the digital license has been issued it won't go away.

(On the other hand, if you were to find the system is on a KMS channel and it's not a corporate managed machine with a legitimate use case for KMS, then it would definitely indicate a fake KMS server being used to activate without a license, which is something I would suspect a ~magic~ USB stick to do.)

Comment: Thanks, and the screenshot added to the question.  Could I ask you to take a look at the pic?  

This "magic" thumb drive added an option to **partition** the hdd.  This seems to have been the problem for UEFI installs as I understand.  Of course, GParted on Linux would do the same.  Absolutely, even from a trusted source, it's still a bit iffy to use a tool just handed to you.  You never know for sure.

Comment: Yes, this looks to be the OEM DM channel.  I ran a truncated version of the command you suggested and omitted the cscript bit.  I'm more reasonably satisified for my purposes.  Definitely open to more information, links, or context, of course.

Comment: Partitioning is not a problem in itself; Windows already creates 3-4 partitions during install time (one of which is actually mandatory for EFI), and the standard Windows install process always has the screen where you can create or delete partitions; that's not necessarily a custom addition.

Comment: I might've not used Ventoy correctly -- but I did get an install screen.  Just no partitioning or formatting options.  Certainly something to revisit.

Answer (score 1):

Running `slmgr.vbs /dlv` brings a `Windows Script Host` popup saying, amongst other things:

```
License Status:  Licensed
Remaining SKU rearm limit:  1001
```

So I much appreciate that suggestion, [Grawity](https://superuser.com/a/1831301/167207).  Speaking for myself, I find that a much clearer result than that everything seems to be working.  The explicit "Licensed" was exactly the litmus test I was looking for.